# Change the size of matrix?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an image that I'm converting to a binary matrix with size `(n,m)`

I need a MATLAB function to reshape the size of this matrix to be `(n,n)`.
Otherwise, would it be possible to make the size of image be (n,n) versus the initial `(n,m)`?

Comment: Need to see some code, so we can help.

Comment: So did what I suggest below work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite easy.  Supposing that your matrix is `A` and is `n x m`. I'm assuming you'll want to **zero-pad** the matrix, meaning that the extra elements would be set to 0.  You would simply do this:

```
[n,m] = size(A);
A(:,m+1:n) = 0;
```

The first line of code finds the rows `n` and columns `m` of the matrix `A`.  Next, we will make all of the rows from the `(m+1)`th column to the `n`th column all 0 which effectively makes this a `n x n` matrix.

## Example Run

Here's an example with a `4 x 2` matrix `A`, and the process requires that we change the size so that `A` is `4 x 4`.

```
>> A = rand(4,2)

A =

    0.9575    0.9572
    0.9649    0.4854
    0.1576    0.8003
    0.9706    0.1419

>> [n,m] = size(A);
>> A(:,m+1:n) = 0

A =

    0.9575    0.9572         0         0
    0.9649    0.4854         0         0
    0.1576    0.8003         0         0
    0.9706    0.1419         0         0
```

## Minor Note

This assumes that the number of rows is greater than the number of columns... I'm assuming that this is a requirement on your end. If this is not the case, then the above code won't work.  You can make the algorithm agnostic whereas you would zero-pad the matrix in the dimension that has the least amount of entries, but I'll leave that to you as an exercise.